# SQL Exception cannot issue statements that do not produce result sets- Java

Tags: java, mysql

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    
    String name = rs.getString("NAME");
    
    System.out.println(name);
    
    st.close();
    con.close();
}
```

: When I run this code this is the error i am getting..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Statement.executeQuery() cannot issue statements that do not produce result sets.
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: What is the query you are doing ? As of this code query is not defined. If you are doing an update, then use `executeUpdate`

Comment: Thanks it worked i am doing an update only

Answer (score -1):

In my case the solution was to downgrade from "mysql-connector-java-8.0.30" to "mysql-connector-java-8.0.18".